# Flex Mouse Cursor Type -or- Determining if a Component is a Control

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

How would you programatically obtain the type of cursor currently being used by the app? I want to check if it is a `MouseCursor.HAND`.

My reason for this is that I have a mask at the application level that I place round a component when the data in that component is being edited in-line (e.g. `DataGrid`). If the user clicks outside of the component while editing I show an alert warning them that they can't navigate away during an edit.

I would like to only show the alert and `preventDefault()` when the user clicks on a 'clickable' component; i.e. one that may cause them to navigate away or open another window. But allow the click when they click on a non-clickable component; e.g. blank space, or a piece of text they want to copy.

Any answers to my original question or alternative solutions are most welcome.

Comment: And what if the hand cursor is turned off?

Comment: Using a combo of getObjectsUnderPoint and checking if(object is InteractiveObject) can tell you if the objects under some point are "clickable" (not necessarily if they have a click handlers registered, you would need to use hasEventListener to get that info).  I'm of the feeling that something like what Jason suggested below is probably a better approach.

Comment: Thanks @shaunhusain. I explained below why I chose not to go with JasonReeves' approach. I have tried both InteractiveObject and hasEventListener and found that neither covered all the controls I'm interested in, or covered too many. That's how I came to the hand cursor theory.

Comment: Why not turn the problem on it's ear? Don't try to figure out if the thing they clicked on is going to result in navigating away. Let it happen, and then in the code that handles the navigation stop the navigation if they are editing. If you use the Parsley, Swiz, or Spring Actionscript, there is a nice Cairngorm Navigation library that lets you do this easily.

Comment: No problem, another option I could think of (though it is still some leg work) is to create an interface that you then implement in extensions of the basecomponents that you want to have the behavior act on, for example if you've got LinkButton's and Button's you want to apply the behavior to (but not all of them) you can extend LinkButton implements INotDuringEdit then use your extension in places you want it to have some other behavior and go back to the method I'm talking about (just checking for your custom interface instead).  Not super fast to implement but should be easy enough to maint

Answer (score 2):

why not set a boolean:

```
private var _isEditing:Boolean = false;
```

then when they begin editing set _isEditing = true;  when they save or quit _isEditing = false;

then on the actionable component's click handler check the flag:

```
if (_isEditing){
    Alert.show("hey you can't do this");
} else {
    do whatever else here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my approach allows you to dispatch an event whenever you begin/end editing which is managed at the application level, rather than placing click listeners on every possible clickable control. It's more maintainable.